# determine value range of template type in C++

Tags: c++, templates, types, range

In a template function, I like to determine the range for the value of its template type. For specific type, like int, INT_MAX and INT_MIN are what I want. But how to do the same for a template type?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: That depends on what the type looks like. Some more details would be useful. What kind of template types are you thinking of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For numeric types, you can use the [`std::numeric_limits`](http://www2.roguewave.com/support/docs/sourcepro/edition9/html/stdlibref/numeric-limits.html) class template in the `<limits>` header.

Answer (score 0):

This is done with type traits like [those from boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

See the [<limits>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/limits/) header and [std::numeric_limits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/limits/numeric_limits/)